# If picture width is smaller than transparent box content start new line

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

[image: example]

```
$('.img-rate').each(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        var n = $(".img-rate").width;

        if (n < 100) {
            $('img-rate').hasClass('pull-leftt ')
        } 
        else {
            $("img-rate").css("background", "orange");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow. Please visit the help center and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Comment: Put the picture to your question please - not a link. The first line of your code is not formated as code. And please *ask a question*. There is only code!

Answer (score 0):

i think $('.img-rate') is a parent class of your both image container, if not change this line and use parent class instead,

second change is wrap your $('.img-rate').each(function(){}) code in $(document).ready.

and final change is instead $('img-rate').hasClass('pull-leftt ') use $('img-rate').addClass('pull-leftt ');

let me know if this work for you.

Comment: No )) i find problem but i don't know how fix it. I am using jquery lib: justifiedGallery and when i am using each picture width to check if it's < 100. Than all the time after script is load it's taking for all img one width, but img width on gallery is different